# Display two Outlook calendars merged in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, outlook

I need to somehow connect calendars from my company's Outlook account to our Sharepoint intranet. And display them in Sharepoint merged together...It's just for read only... It isn't necessary to edit calendar from sharepoint...just what is added to multiple calendars in outlook, should be displeyed in one calendar in SP.

Answer (score 0):

One way to export outlook calendar to SharePoint is using the connect to Outlook action in SharePoint Calendar. In that way you can copy events between Outlook and SharePoint. However there may be changes to the event title(adding "copy" ).

Steps here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhupNIhJPZY

For displaying two calendars in one, you can use overlay.

A tutorial here:https://sharepointmaven.com/roll-calendars-sharepoint/

Comment: yes, i know this steps but I need to connect existing outlook calendar to SP site. Maybe it could work with power automate...but thanks anyway. If I will not find solution, I will use yours